# Unable to switch to IFrame using Android WebDriver

Tags: android, webdriver

I was wondering if someone could point me to what I am doing wrong exactly. I am trying to access an iframe using Android WebDriver. The iframe opens up when I click on a Sign in link on the home page. Below is a snippet of the src code that has the iframe id that I am trying to access-

```
<div class="dialog" style="background-color: rgb(232, 235, 238); color: rgb(51, 51, 51);">
   <iframe id="registration-dialog-frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://test.com"   border="0" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 235px;">
     <html>
   </iframe>
 <span id="signin-cancel" class="cancelButton">Cancel</span>
```

I wait till the iframe opens up, check if the frame id is present and then use switchTo() to switch to that iframe like this

```
driver.switchTo().frame("registration-dialog-frame");
```

I get a

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error: {"message":"Cannot read property 'document' of undefined"}
```

When I try this

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.id("registration-dialog-frame")));
```

I get a

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.android.library.DomWindow
```

Is this a Android WebDriver thing? Has anyone else come across this similar kind of errors when switching to iframe? Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check the number of frames present in that page by looking at code and use index to switch into that particular frame as shown below.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(frameindex);
```

Ex: To Switch to the first frame, use below line.

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```